# Lumen email attachment weird behavior

Tags: php, laravel, email, lumen

Whenever I try to send a mail with lumen I get this error (After waiting):
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

This weird error pops-up whenever I try to execute t

```
    $mailer = app()->make('mailer');
    $mailer->send('template', [] , function ($message) use ($file) {

        $message->from('test@example.com', 'test');
        $message->to('test@example.com');
        // $message->attach($file, ['mime' => 'pdf']); <-- problem

    });
```

However, this code works like expected.
Whenever I uncomment the line $message->attach the page won't load anymore.

No the PDF isn't exceptionally bit, I can't track the issue...
Anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was on google's side.
I used a smtp server from google. 
It seems there server blocked my request when I added a file as attachment.
Still don't know why, but it works now! (using mailgun).